# Why TFS doesn't actually delete the workspace?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

We changed our domain from say x.com to y.local, and now we experience something really wierd on a client's machine.

We want to delete all of the old workspaces, so that we can bind them (map them) again to the new TFS structure.

We execute this command:

```
tf workspace /delete workspaceName;workspaceOwner /login:administrator
```

and it indeed tells us that the requested workspace is deleted. Then in Visual Studio, what we see is that by refreshing the connection to TFS, the workspace is back.

We doubted workspace caching, thus we searched and found [this link](http://gregdoesit.com/2009/01/tfs-deleting-old-workspaces/), which proposes to run the following command to get rid of all cached workspaces:

```
tf workspaces /remove:*
```

But still we can't map the new structure to that folder on our system (we do need that folder, it's vital for our deployment). TFS says that this folder (or this workspace) is already in use.

We even uninstalled VS and reinstalled it, but no result.

Please, is there any straightforward way to delete a workspace explicitly more than executing these commands? This problem is driving us crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Download and use the [TFS sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), log on as an account with "Project Administrator" privileges and use the Workspace sidekick to search for and edit / remove the problem workspaces

Answer (score 2):

you should check the build agents/definition, they have their own workspace and folder mappings